# How to implement both device_preview and responsive_framework packages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I would like to use both device_preview and ChangeNotifierProvider in my application. To do so, I need to add the respective codes to the builder property of MaterialApp.
However, since there is only one builder property in MaterialApp widget,
How do I implement device preview too?

```
void main() {
  // DevicePreview(builder: (context)=> MyApp);
  runApp(
    // ignore: missing_required_param
    ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
      create: (_) => ThemeChanger(lightTheme),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

For reference:
https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview/example

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
runApp(
DevicePreview(
  enabled: !kReleaseMode,
  builder: (context) => MyApp(), // Wrap your app
),
);


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
locale: DevicePreview.locale(context),
  builder: (context, child) {
    child = ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
      BouncingScrollWrapper.builder(context, child!),
      maxWidth: 1200,
      minWidth: 450,
      defaultScale: true,
breakpoints: [
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(450, name: MOBILE),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(600, name: TABLET),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1000, name: TABLET),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(1200, name: DESKTOP),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(2460, name: "4K"),
      ],
      landscapeBreakpoints: [
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScaleDown(800, name: TABLET),
      ],
 background: Container(
        color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
      ),
    );
    child = DevicePreview.appBuilder(context, child);
    return child;
 },
  home: HomePage(),
  theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(platform: TargetPlatform.android),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
);
}
}
```

Comment: It is only working on reasonable size models but doesn't work on smaller models (iPhoneSE) or larger models (iPad).